# Where to start diagnosing simple cronjob

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a Ubuntu server with a single user and the following crontab:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and crontab(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
MAILTO=<my email>
* * * * * echo "Test"
```

As simple as this cron job is, I'm not getting any emails. I've also tried modifying it as follows (in case there's an issue with my email):

```
* * * * * echo "Test" >> test.txt
```

but the file `test.txt` is never created.

This seems like a **really** simple issue, but normally when I have trouble with cron jobs it's actually running and the job is just throwing an error. I don't know how to start diagnosing it when the job isn't even running.

### Update with output of `service cron status`

```
sbarnett@sbarnett:~$ service cron status
Failed to get properties: Access denied
sbarnett@sbarnett:~$ sudo service cron status
[sudo] password for sbarnett:
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-08-15 14:15:52 MST; 3 weeks 1 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 1682 (cron)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─1682 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Sep 07 09:55:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3144]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 07 09:55:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3145]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 07 10:05:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3151]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 07 10:05:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3152]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 07 10:05:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3151]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Sep 07 10:15:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3156]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 07 10:15:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3157]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 07 10:17:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3159]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 07 10:17:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3160]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 07 10:17:01 sbarnett.vm CRON[3159]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about `cron` (so this could be complete crap), but does it make sense to wildcard _all_ five fields? When would you expect the job to run with this setting, at every given time, every day? I'd try to put something in the minute field at least.

Comment: Check that the `cron` service is running: `service cron status`; if not, then `sudo service cron start`.

Comment: @Aganju - All fields set to `*` is perfectly valid: it runs a task every minute.

Comment: I've run `service cron status` and it seems like it's running from what I can tell (I updated the question with the details). Regarding `mail`, it is installed and functioning (I can directly send an email from the command line) however the modified cron job (dumping to `test.txt`) should work regardless of the mail agent.

Comment: Your status output shows no sign of running your test entry. I didn't need `sudo` for `service cron status`, and the fact that you needed it indicates that there could be something wrong with your permissions, but I can't imagine what. One other possibility is an error on the `MAILTO:` line (such as unmatched quotes) which is causing the next line to be ignored: try commenting it out and see if the test entry now executes.

Comment: Interspersed with lines similar to those in your status output I also get `pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user AFH by (uid=0)`, then `(AFH) CMD (echo "Test" >> test.txt)`, then
`pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user AFH`.

Comment: So since you mentioned I shouldn't need `sudo`, I started googling the error: `Failed to get properties: Access denied`. I found a lot of forums and issue posts suggesting that updates and reboots can fix an issue like this. I did a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo shutdown -r` and when the VM came back up, my cron jobs started firing immediately

Answer (score 1):

My particular issue seemed to be a strange one, the full details of which I don't entirely understand - but through some guesswork and reading various forum posts I found the answer.

Sometimes OS updates can screw with the permissions on your cron files. Any (or all) of the following can fix it:

- `sudo service cron reload`
- `sudo service cron restart`
- `sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart`
- `shutdown -r now`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Basically:

- Try to restart the cron daemon
- Try restarting your computer
- If all else fails, there may be an update that fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu the crontab is a bit different, there is a "user" field after the time selector...

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
```

To debug you can try to use a simple command such as:

```
logger "This goes to /var/log/syslog"
```

And check that if goes to that log file at the expected times. Then call a script instead (a script that itself calls `logger` ...)

Comment: That field is not present in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The crontab extract above is from my own PC that runs Kubuntu 16.04 and I have the same in a server that runs Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: This is not the issue I'm having nor does it resolve my issue. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and there's no user column. Thank you for trying, though.